# highlight a whole series when hovering with the mouse

Tags: javascript, hover, highcharts, highlight

When I hover a point with the mouse, the point is highlighted. Is it possible to highlight the whole series in place of the single point?
An example in [jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jU7Bq/1/):

```
$(function () {
    var chart;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container'
            },
            series: [{
                type: 'line',
                data: [[0, 1.11], [1, 4.51], [2, 4]],
            },{
                type: 'line',
                data: [[0, 2.11], [1, 3.51], [2, 2]],
            }]
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: It's the default behaviour. If you take a look it happens on your demo.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I don't know why I did'nt realize it. Anyway, I want to highlight the line to a larger width than in the example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the line width of the series as it is described in the api:

> http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.states.hover.lineWidth

```
plotOptions: {
            series: {
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        enabled: true,
                        lineWidth: 5
                    }
                }
            }
        },
```